# Hide/Unhide rows based on more than one cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

Please help me

I am using the following code to hide rows if cell values are 0:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim LastRow As Long, c As Range
Application.EnableEvents = False
LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
On Error Resume Next
For Each c In Range("I9:I48")
   If c.Value = 0 Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf c.Value > 0 Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next
On Error GoTo 0
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

It works perfectly, but I would like for the code to also check column `K` (the same range `K9:K48`) if both cells in a row are 0 then the row must be hidden. How can I change the code to do this?

Comment: The same range I9:I48 or K9:K48? ^^ Anyway, maybe it would be better to move your question to StackOverflow

Comment: @duDE VBA questions are on-topic here as well, so no need to migrate.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
....
For Each c In Range("I9:I48")
   If (c.Value = 0 OR c.Offset(1,0).Value = 0) Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ....
```